# SCORM 2004 3rd edition Sequencing

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

I have a question about SCORM 2004 3rd edition Sequencing.

- Root (flow=true)

  - Activity 1
  - Activity 2 (flow=true, preConditionRule=>condition=always, Action=skip)

    - Activity 3
    - Activity 4
  - Activity 5

Suppose the Activity 5 is the current activity and the learner triggers Previous navigation request; In this case, which activity should be delivered next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Action value of Activity 2 is set to skip, the "Previous Button" will take us back to Activity 1 jumping over Activity 2 and its child activities 3+4.

Comment: Suppose that the SCO sets "adl.nav.request" data model element to "previous" and the calls Terminate(""). What about this case?

Comment: The same thing will happen here as well.